# How to reference non-static method 'findViewById' from a static context?

Tags: java, android, static, static-methods, android-context

I have just started with android development, and I am stuck at this:

```
static Handler h = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        TextView buttonmain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonmainid);
        if(buttonmain.getText()=="Text1")
            buttonmain.setText("Text2");
        else
            buttonmain.setText("Text1");
    }
};
```

this gives an error regarding the accessing of findViewById() method inside a static context.

Comment: Why `Handler` must be static?

Comment: why do you need the Handler ?

Comment: To prevent memory leaks. That's what I found as a warning while using it.@mr.icetea

Comment: Text View is define in on create view and static also, the call in under a static method

Comment: `static` stuff get loaded when class is loading and `views` are available on `context`. `Context` is initialized when class is `initialized`. That means, you have to wait to get the views untill context of activity is available. `Context` will be available in `onCreate()`, so typically views are loaded there. I would suggest you to have a quick look in Android Guideline (best place for such info)

Comment: I was going through Threads. And it said use Handlers if you need to change the interface while the thread is running. @Blackbelt

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks @GauravGupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't make your handler static in this case. Indeed, non-static handlers do cause memory leaks, but far from always. If you just started Android development, you are probably not going to run into a scenario where it causes a memory leak.

The problem mostly occurs when you are sending messages to your handler that are not being processed before the class is destroyed. In other words, for a memory leak to occur the following has to happen:

1. Create instance
2. Create handler
3. Send message to handler
4. Destroy class
5. Handler handles message.

In this case there'd be a memory leak. But I very highly doubt this'll happen.

But, to answer your question, a simple way to do this is to add the following to your class:

```
static MyClass instance;
```

and in the constructor:

```
MyClass.instance = this;
```

Do be careful with this though, this will never work well when you get multiple instances of the same class, so you might want to look into singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You need and instance of the Activity with the contentView from where you want to get a View.

But... Looking at your code i think you should pass the TextView instance directly.

Hope this helps.